# what is torch's unsqueeze equivalence with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, torch

what is torch's unsqueeze  equivalence with tensorflow?

```
#tensorflow auto-broadcasts singleton dimensions
lower_bounds = tf.argmax(set_1[:, :2].unsqueeze(1), set_2[:, :2].unsqueeze(0))  # (n1, n2, 2)
upper_bounds = tf.argmin(set_1[:, 2:].unsqueeze(1), set_2[:, 2:].unsqueeze(0))  # (n1, n2, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you wanna try this:
`tf.expand_dims(x, axis)`

Answer (score 2):

[tf.expand_dims](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) is what you are looking for.

```
tf.expand_dims(
    input, axis, name=None
)
```

> Given a tensor input, this operation inserts a dimension of size 1 at the dimension index axis of input's shape. The dimension index axis starts at zero; if you specify a negative number for axis it is counted backward from the end.

Example

```
t = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]       # [2, 3]
tf.shape(tf.expand_dims(t, 0))  # [1, 2, 3]
tf.shape(tf.expand_dims(t, 1))  # [2, 1, 3]
tf.shape(tf.expand_dims(t, -1)) # [2, 3, 1]
```